# Redraw image on canvas on touch event?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to redraw an image on the canvas on an `onTouch` event. I am able to draw the image on the canvas, but I want the image to redraw at a particular `x,y`.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)

{

     mBitmap1   = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ab);
 mBitmap2   = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ab);
 this.canvas=canvas;

     Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2 , y2, p);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1, 70, 60, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1, 185, 60, null);
}


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int x=(int)event.getX();
        Log.i("***********xPos","="+x);
        final int y=(int)event.getY();
        Log.i("***********yPos","="+y);

        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {

        }
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap1,50+x,60,null );
            this.postInvalidate();

        }
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. You are calling `postinvalidate()` method each time when `action.down` is called, so it calls ultimately call `ondraw()`. So it will redraw it on bitmap for particular setted value at which you put in ondraw again.

So you looks that it remain unchanged.

Follow these steps:

1. use some public variables for drawing bitmaps in ondraw method for x and y axis, lets say initx and inity
2. then on touch event:update this value by adding your x and y value to initx and inity resp.

   ```
   like:initx=initx+x;
   inity=inity+y;
   ```

And last in cation down event just call `post.invalidate` or `ondraw` method.

Answer (score 0):

See the MotionEvent class that provides the coordinates of where the user touched the screen.