# how to know density of device?

Tags: android

As we can get the resolution in android, but how can we know the density of the device (screen) ?

thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Execute the following code:

```
float scale = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

and check the value of `scale`:

- `0.75` means *low density*
- `1.0` means *standard (medium) density*
- `1.5` means *high (large) density*
- `2.0` means *extra high density*
- `3.0` means *extra extra high density*
- `4.0` means *extra extra extra high density*

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more info.

Comment: hi chirag if possible pls see the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758278/redraw-image-on-canvas-on-touch-event

Comment: today there is also tvdpi and xhdpi . probably more to come in the future. more information here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html